# Suspend turned off, but computer keeps suspending

Tags: suspend

I'm running ubuntu 12.04 with a fairly fresh install (2 update sessions)

I turned off the suspend function in BIOS and System Settings but my computer keeps suspending about every 5 or 10 minutes of inactivity. I just switched the setting to 1 hour, hoping I'll at least get a little more time, but I would really like it to never suspend.

Thanks everybody in advance.

Comment: I switched suspend to 1 hour and nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You not only have to set the suspend option in the "Power" tab of the system settings, but you also have to go to the "Brightnesss & Lock" tab in the system settings window and change that setting also.

I figured I would leave this up and answer (instead of deleting), just in case someone has a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you have gnome-tweaks or unity-tweaks installed just look through power option in that you might see **suspend when laptop lid is closed** option just deselect it as shown in image.

[image]

**Note:** I capture this image from my **ubuntu 18.04** so just in case you might have different options